# Statically configure IP on remote PC with DNS

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have this powershell script to statically set IP on a remote PC that is currently using DHCP to receive an IP. So the script is able to set the IP, but because it's on a different VLAN it disconnects and isn't able to complete the DNS part. How can I have it set both IP and DNS then disconnect?

```
$IP = 192.168.1.10
$Machine = "Server1"
$Mask = 24
$Gateway = "192.168.1.1"
$DNS = "8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1"


Get-NetAdapter -name 'Ethernet0 3' -CimSession $Machine | Set-DNSClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $DNS
Get-NetAdapter -name 'Ethernet0 3' -CimSession $Machine | new-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $IP -PrefixLength $Mask -Defaultgateway $Gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing a specific `CimSession` which could close between commands, try starting a remote disconnected PSSession with multiple commands:

```
$DCS = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -InDisconnectedSession -ScriptBlock {
    Get-NetAdapter -name 'Ethernet0 3' | Set-DNSClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $Using:DNS
    Get-NetAdapter -name 'Ethernet0 3' | New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $Using:IP -PrefixLength $Using:Mask -Defaultgateway $Gateway
}
```

Optionally, you can then try and reconnect the session - either to  receive any output from the commands you ran or to continue where you left off. This can misbehave when changing IPs though

```sh
sleep $seconds
# Requires your PC to be able to resolve the old computer name to the new address:
Receive-PSSession $DCS
# Sometimes works better to get an updated session object first:
Get-PSSession $DCS | Receive-PSSession

# If nothing else, you can get the session object again with the new IP. 
# This requires HTTPS winrm, and explicit credentials:
Get-PSSession -ComputerName $IP -UseSSL -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: So the "Job" ran but didn't make the IP changes on the remote machine. However, it said job completed on remote machine when I check for job status.

Comment: @Jon My mistake - it seems like `Invoke-Command` waits for reconnection unless you use the `-InDisconnectedSession` parameter. I've updated my answer